# Need software to read geo information from tif

Tags: coordinate-system, geotiff-tiff, latitude-longitude

I am trying to verify the lat/lon and ECEF values that I have determined for a very specific and unusual situation (a geotif file), and it would be great if I could find some software to read them.

What software can I use that will just open a tif and show me its ECEF and lat/lon corners ? (open source or trial)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[GDAL](http://gdal.org/) is your friend in this (as well as a lot of other...) situation.